# Notes not displaying when passed to Square app using SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, square-connect

Why do the `notes` not show up in the Square App when processing a payment? See screenshots below. Here is the SDK method I am using to call the Square App.

```
- (void) sdktest {
    NSURL *const callbackURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"SomeCallBackURL-Here"];

    SCCMoney *const amount = [SCCMoney moneyWithAmountCents:500 currencyCode:@"USD" error:NULL];

    [SCCAPIRequest setClientID:SQUARE_PROD_APP_ID];
    NSError * error;
    SCCAPIRequest *request = [SCCAPIRequest requestWithCallbackURL:callbackURL
                                                            amount:amount
                                                    userInfoString:@"My User info string"
                                                        merchantID:nil
                                                             notes:@"My Note"
                                                        customerID:nil
                                              supportedTenderTypes:SCCAPIRequestTenderTypeAll
                                                 clearsDefaultFees:NO
                                   returnAutomaticallyAfterPayment:YES
                                                             error:&error];

    [SCCAPIConnection performRequest:request error:&error];

    if (error != nil) { NSLog(@"ERROR IN SDKWAY: %@", error.localizedDescription); }
}
```

But when the Square app is opened all that shows is the price. I would like to show the user what they are paying for.

On return the data package includes the `notes` and `userInfoString`

[image]

Screenshots:
Clicking the "back" arrow just takes you back to the test app.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At this point in the checkout flow, the Point of Sale app does not show more info about the purchase, except for price. If you want your users to see which items you are paying for, you should display them in your app before you make the switch to Square Point of Sale.